# How to add rich text column to Access database table using C# and OleDB?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

in an Access database we can set `Text Format` attribute of a `Long Text` column to either `Plain Text` or `Rich Text`.

How can we add a Rich text column to a table programmatically in C# using OleDb API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a text field in an Access table to a rich text memo using VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828561/how-to-convert-a-text-field-in-an-access-table-to-a-rich-text-memo-using-vba)

Comment: edited my question to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we add a Rich text column to a table programmatically in C# using OleDb API?

We can't do it using OleDb. We need to use Access DAO for that:

```cs
// required COM reference: Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
//
// using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao; ...
var dbe = new DBEngine();
Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb");
TableDef tbd = db.TableDefs["MyTable"];  // existing table
var fld = new Field();
fld.Name = "MyRichMemo";
fld.Type = (short) DataTypeEnum.dbMemo;
tbd.Fields.Append(fld);
// now set "Text Format" property to "Rich Text"
fld.Properties.Append(fld.CreateProperty("TextFormat", DataTypeEnum.dbByte, 1));
db.Close();
```

Comment: Does this approach also works with access 2003 (.mdb) files? What about Microsoft OLE Provider for Jet 4.0?

Comment: @mohas - Yes, the same code will work with an Access_2003-format .mdb file. As for `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`, it won't help you; you need to use Access DAO,

Answer (score -1):

Answering the question: "How to add a rich text column to an Access table".

Access 2010 and above allows rich text to be saved in a memo.
Below is the c# OleDB code I have used to add a memo column to an Access table.

```
public OleDbConnection myAccessConnection = new OleDbConnection();

myAccessConnection.ConnectionString = 
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\myAccessDb.accdb";

OleDbCommand sqlCommand = new OleDbCommand();

myAccessConnection.Open();
sqlCommand.Connection = myAccessConnection;

sqlCommand.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE [MyTableInMyAccessDb] ADD MyMemo MEMO";

sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

myAccessConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Not sure why someone would down vote this answer.  I created this answer from code that runs successfully in an application I developed.  I'd be grateful for any helpful feedback.

Comment: It looks as if the answer you provided wasn't relevant to the question asked.  The OP wanted to know how to create a long text/memo field with the property of holding "rich text".  The result of your code would simply add a long memo field of subtype "plain text".  That said, your answer isn't wrong, nor does does it do any harm, so I would see no reason to actively vote it down.