# Access change memo field from "plain text" to "rich text" using VBScript

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript

i have a question about changing a memofield from "plain text" to "rich text" using VBScript, i found some solutions here and on the internet but all the solutions are for VBScript within access. I try to start an vbscript through Windows, but my script doesn't work. I'm kindly new to VBScripting so i hope you guys can help me. I used an example from the forum for my script:
[How to convert a text field in an Access table to a rich text memo using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828561/how-to-convert-a-text-field-in-an-access-table-to-a-rich-text-memo-using-vba)

My Script:

```
Dim db
Dim tdf
Dim fld1
Dim fld2
Set accessApp = GetObject("D:\test.mdb")
Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase "D:\test.mdb", true
    accessApp.visible = false
    accessApp.UserControl = true 

Set accessApp.db =  CurrentDB
Set accessApp.tdf = db.TableDefs("Database")
Set accessApp.fld1 = tdf.Fields("Name_Memofield1")
Set accessApp.fld2 = tdf.Fields("Name_Memofield2")
Debug.Print "acTextFormatPlain: " & acTextFormatPlain & _
    "; acTextFormatHTMLRichText: " & acTextFormatHTMLRichText
With fld1.Properties("TextFormat")
    Debug.Print "TextFormat: " & .Value
    If .Value = acTextFormatPlain Then
        .Value = acTextFormatHTMLRichText
        Debug.Print "TextFormat changed to: " & .Value
    End If
End With    
With fld2.Properties("TextFormat")
    Debug.Print "TextFormat: " & .Value
    If .Value = acTextFormatPlain Then
        .Value = acTextFormatHTMLRichText
        Debug.Print "TextFormat changed to: " & .Value
    End If
End With
```

The error what occures tells me that the problem is in the "Set accessApp.db =  CurrentDB" the error which occured is: "Object doesn't support this prperty or method accessApp.db" If i change "accessApp.db" to "db" an other error occures: "Object required: 'CurrentDB' "

Comment: Code from access DB will not work directly as vbs script file. You need to connect to Ms Access DB through a connection string and then write the logic to convert PlainText to RichText.

Comment: You have a few unnecessary lines. Try `Set db = accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase "D:\test.mdb", true` and skip `Set accessApp.db =  CurrentDB`, you do not need it. db is not a property of Access Application. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj250267.aspx

Comment: @MukulVarshney that is not quite true. You probably will not be able to change a field type with an ADODB connection, but you can with an Access Application Object.

Comment: @Fionnuala you are correct. What I meant is -- its not necessary that every statement in VBA Access will work as it is in VBScript (i.e. without changing). We may have to re-write those statements

Comment: @All thanks for the reactions. @ Mukul is this different than changing an field form Yes/No to Text? Because i have also an script to change the data type and that's working fine. @ Fionnuala I tried your solution but unfortunately it wont work, i get an error "Expected end of statement" line 11 char 40 so thats whe the path "D:\test.mdb" begins

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the code below. It will need tidying.

```
Option Explicit

Dim accessApp
Dim db
Dim dbname
Dim tdf
Dim fld1
Dim fld2
Dim acTextFormatPlain
Dim acTextFormatHTMLRichText
Dim dbInteger

'acTextFormatPlain=0
'acTextFormatHTMLRichText=1
dbInteger=3

dbname="D:\Test.mdb"

Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase(dbname)

set db=accessapp.CurrentDb

Set tdf = db.TableDefs("2emails")

'The property may not exist
SetFieldProperty tdf.Fields(1), "TextFormat", dbInteger, 0
With tdf.Fields(1).Properties("TextFormat")
    If .Value = 0 Then
        .Value = 1
        msgbox "TextFormat changed to: " & .Value
    End If
End With

Sub SetFieldProperty(ByVal fld , ByVal strPropertyName , ByVal iDataType , ByVal vValue )
    Dim prp

    Set prp = Nothing

    On Error Resume Next
    Set prp = fld.Properties(strPropertyName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If prp Is Nothing Then
        Set prp = fld.CreateProperty(strPropertyName, iDataType, vValue)
        fld.Properties.Append prp 
    Else
        prp.Value = vValue
    End If
End Sub
```