# MS Access underline text in a Table

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have long Text field in a table in MS ACCESS. I need to underline it for specific text in a field. I tried to change Text format to Rich Text in the design view , but I am getting:

> Error : Operation is not supported for this type of Object

In the table I have 320 rows. I need to Underline for N.J.S.A. only in the long text.

Please help me regarding this. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Well... you have to get that field property changed from plain text to rich text for this to work and design view should handle this. If not try the below code.

```
Public Sub TestUnderline()
Dim db                              As DAO.Database
Dim tbl                             As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld                             As Field
Dim rst                             As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL                          As String
Dim strString                       As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tbl = db.TableDefs("Table1") 'Change to your table name
Set fld = tbl.Fields("TestField") 'Change to your field name

With fld.Properties("TextFormat")
    If .Value = acTextFormatPlain Then
        .Value = acTextFormatHTMLRichText
    End If
End With

strSQL = "SELECT TestField " & _ 'Change to your Field name
         "FROM Table1;" 'Change to your table name
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Do While Not rst.EOF
    If InStr(1, rst![TestField], "N.J.S.A") Then 'Change to your field name
        strString = Replace(rst![TestField], "N.J.S.A", "<u>N.J.S.A</u>") 'Change to your field name
        rst.Edit
        rst![TestField] = strString 'Change to your field name
        rst.Update
    End If
    rst.MoveNext
Loop


EndCode:
If Not rst Is Nothing Then
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End If
If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
    Set tbl = Nothing
End If
If Not db Is Nothing Then
    Set db = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```

Credit given to: 
[How to convert a text field in an Access table to a rich text memo using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828561/how-to-convert-a-text-field-in-an-access-table-to-a-rich-text-memo-using-vba)

and:
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1538917

Comment: Chris, Thanks a lot for your quick responce.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks a lot for your quick help I tried the code but getting as <u>N.J.S.A.</u> in pdf output.No errors in code.

Comment: The code should only be underlining N.J.S.A. in your table... nothing about pdf output. What are you trying to do with a pdf output?

Comment: Based on Table I am generating report, That report outputting to pdf document. The code helped me to get underline the text in the table. The same content not outputting properly.

Comment: DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "YourTableName", acFormatPDF, "Your file location\TestFile.pdf"